# Can you have multiple bindings on one button?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I am trying to have a command binding and a IsVisible binding on one button in a listview. If I have the binding context in the button, the command binding will work and the IsVisible binding will not work. If I remove the Binding Context, the IsVisible binding will work but the Command binding will not work. Does any have a suggestion on how to remedy this situation.

```
<Button BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference icaoDownloads}, 
        Path=BindingContext}"
        Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, 
                                          Path=BindingContext}"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="  Update  "
        BorderColor="DarkSlateGray"
        BorderRadius="5"
        BorderWidth="2"
        Margin="2"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsDownloadable}" />
```

I have a list created from a database set. I am trying to only show the button when the database has an available update. So i want to make the button appear only when there is an update, click the button and download the data to the database and then make the button not visible.

Comment: Could you show code of model is be binded?

Comment: how do you manage the IsDownloadable binding? Please post that code too.

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say multiple binding here?

Comment: I was trying to bind a command for the button and bind the isVisible property to another command. I was able to find a solution.

Comment: I added a solution below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately,xaml not supporting multiple bindings.**

If button is in `ListView`,

`BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference icaoDownloads}, Path=BindingContext}"`

should remove form Button.

**Solution one**:Have a try with follow code:

```
<Button
       Command="{Binding BindingContext.DownloadCommand, Source={x:Reference icaoDownloads}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item},Path=BindingContext}"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="  Update  "
        BorderColor="DarkSlateGray"
        BorderRadius="5"
        BorderWidth="2"
        Margin="2"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsDownloadable}" />
```

---

**Solution two**: if **Xaml** code as follow:

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewbig" ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" 
                HasUnevenRows="true" 
                ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped"
                ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="{Binding Location}"
                VerticalOptions="End" 
                Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleTextStyle}" />
                <Button Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="Click"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsDownloadable}"
                    Clicked="OnClicked"
                    Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="2"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.Column="3" x:Name="progressBar" 
    Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress,Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
    PropertyChanged="ProgressBar_PropertyChanged"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**MonkeysViewModel.cs**

```
    class MonkeysViewModel
    {
        public IList<Monkey> Monkeys { get; private set; }

        private async void ShowCustomerInfo(object obj)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("true" + obj );
        }

        public MonkeysViewModel()
            {


                Monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
                //f = new F[5];
                Monkeys.Add(new Monkey
                {
                    Name = "Baboon",
                    Location = "Africa & Asia",
                    CommandShowInfo = new Command(ShowCustomerInfo),
                    IsDownloadable = true
                });
                ...
                }
            }
    }
```

**Monkey.cs**

```
public class Monkey : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandShowInfo { get; set; }

    private bool isDownloadable = true;
    public bool IsDownloadable
    {
        set
        {
            if (isDownloadable != value)
            {
                isDownloadable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsDownloadable");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return isDownloadable;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here ListView ContentPage : `BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();`

and Test in Button clicked method:

```
void OnClicked(Object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var monkey = btn.BindingContext as Monkey;
    monkey.IsDownloadable = false;
}
```

Maybe problem is binding Model not correctly using.

Comment: If I read the question correctly this should solve the problem. To add to this, it looks like there is an attempt to bind the current item to the command parameter. To bind the entire current BindingContext you can use `{Binding .}`

Comment: @Knoop Yeah, if have soved this problem. Remember to mark it,thanks in advance.^.^

Comment: Jiang I wasn't the one who asked this question, just commented om an improvement.

Comment: @Knoop Okey ,got it.Thanks for improvement ,you are welcome. *.^

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.DownloadCommand, Source={x:Reference TestIcaoContent}}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            BackgroundColor="Black"
                                            TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Text="  Update  "
                                            BorderColor="DarkSlateGray"
                                            BorderRadius="5"
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            Margin="2"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext.IsDownloadable}" />
```

This fixed my problem and let me pass the list item value to the viewmodel.

This is my constructor for the view model:

```
public ICommand NavCommandCommand { get; private set; }
public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
public ICommand DownloadCommand { get; private set; }

        public TestIcaoViewModel()
        {

            //DownloadCommand = new Command(Download);
            DownloadCommand = new Command((e) => { var item = (e as TestLandingViewModel); Download(item.IcaoCode); });

            NavCommandCommand = new Command((e) => { var item2 = (e as TestLandingViewModel); NavCommand(item2.IcaoCode); });
            LoadAirportData();   
        }
```